# Test connection between logstash and aws es cluster

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, logstash, elastic-stack, amazon-elasticsearch

So I have a java program which writes a dummy log to a file dummyLog.log every second.

```
log.error("127.23.12.331 - - [17/May/2015:10:05:03 +0000] \"GET /presentations/logstash-monitorama-2013");
```

My logstash configuration file :

```
input {
    file {
        path => "path to the dummyLog.log"
        type => "application"
        sincedb_path => "...application.db"
    }
}

filter {

}

output {
    amazon_es {
        hosts  => ["<aws es endpoint>"]
        region =>  "us-east-1"
        index => "something"
    }
}
```

My aws elasticsearch cluster's access policy is open to all right now without any restrictions.

I checked "dummyLog.log" and logs are being written to it at every second but I can see nothing being recieved by elasticsearch and nothing comes on kibana. I checked the logstash.log file and it is completely empty.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: And in the other logstash log files ? (logstash.stdout and logstash.err)

Comment: Are you sure there is any data in your elasticsearch cluster (with curl /index name/_search? Sometimes in kibana data does not appear because of the range used.

Comment: was a range problem on kibana! :)

Comment: you should answer your own question then.